# How handle SIGTSTP signal in concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor with 'spawn' start method and mp Manager data

Tags: python, multiprocessing, signals

I am trying to catch a `SIGTSTP` signal to show some data while the program runs. And I am using `multiprocessing.Manager().dict()` to store data.
If send `SIGTSTP` all the processes are suspended, but if I try to continue the process (using `fg`) all the processes are hanging.

I have a class to handle the signal.

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO, format="%(processName)s %(relativeCreated)d %(message)s"
)

class SignalHandler(object):
    def __init__(
        self, handling_object, sigint_callback, sigtstp_callback, callback_args
    ) -> None:
        self.h_object = handling_object
        self.sigint_callback = sigint_callback
        self.sigtstp_callback = sigtstp_callback
        self.callback_args = callback_args

    def setup(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.sigint_handler)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, self.sigtstp_handler)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGCONT, self.sigcont_handler)

    def sigint_handler(self, signum, frame):
        if self.h_object is not None:
            logger.critical(
                f"You pressed Ctrl+C, calling callback function with {self.callback_args} and exiting"
            )
            self.sigint_callback(*self.callback_args)
            sys.exit(1)
        else:
            logger.critical("You pressed Ctrl+C, object is not initialized. Exiting")
            sys.exit(1)

    def sigtstp_handler(self, signum, frame):
        if self.h_object is not None:
            logger.critical(
                f"You pressed Ctrl+Z, calling callback function with {self.callback_args} and stalling"
            )
            self.sigtstp_callback(*self.callback_args)
        else:
            logger.critical("You pressed Ctrl+Z, object is not initialized. Stalling")

        signal.signal(signum, signal.SIG_DFL)
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signum)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, self.sigtstp_handler)

    def sigcont_handler(self, signum, frame):
        logger.info("Continuing generation")
        time.sleep(1)
```

And a class to do the work.

```
class Model(object):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        logger.info("Model")
        self.data = mp.Manager().dict()
        self.signal_handler = SignalHandler(self, self.dump, self.dump, (out,))

    def worker(self, value, lock=None):
        logger.info(value)
        self.data[value] = "added"
        time.sleep(1)

    def run(self):
        logger.info("run")

        try:
            logger.info("try")
            with ProcessPoolExecutor(
                max_workers=4,
                mp_context=mp.get_context("spawn"),
                initializer=self.signal_handler.setup,
            ) as executor:
                for row in range(16):
                    fargs = (row, )
                    future = executor.submit(self.worker, *fargs)
                    logger.info("submitted")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Caught KeyboardInterrupt")

    def dump(self, out):
        print(self.data, file=out, flush=True)
```

Python main

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    out = None
    m = Model()
    m.run()
    m.dump(out)
```

When sent a `SIGTSTP` all the processes are stalling.

```
^ZSpawnProcess-5 1170 You pressed Ctrl+Z, calling callback function with (None,) and stalling
SpawnProcess-4 1171 You pressed Ctrl+Z, calling callback function with (None,) and stalling
SpawnProcess-3 1174 You pressed Ctrl+Z, calling callback function with (None,) and stalling
SpawnProcess-2 1178 You pressed Ctrl+Z, calling callback function with (None,) and stalling
```

When continuing the processes (using `SIGCONT` or `fg`) get a print as the number of procs and hang after that.

```
SpawnProcess-5 10912 Continuing generation
SpawnProcess-4 10914 Continuing generation
SpawnProcess-2 10920 Continuing generation
SpawnProcess-3 10916 Continuing generation
{0: 'added', 1: 'added', 2: 'added', 3: 'added', 4: 'added', 5: 'added', 6: 'added', 7: 'added'}
{0: 'added', 1: 'added', 2: 'added', 3: 'added', 4: 'added', 5: 'added', 6: 'added', 7: 'added'}
{0: 'added', 1: 'added', 2: 'added', 3: 'added', 4: 'added', 5: 'added', 6: 'added', 7: 'added'}
{0: 'added', 1: 'added', 2: 'added', 3: 'added', 4: 'added', 5: 'added', 6: 'added', 7: 'added'}
[hangs here]
```

I tried looking at stack trace to figure out where the processes hang. Two threads are remaining.

```
$ps aux | grep proc_exec
13979  0.4  0.0 283284 12556 pts/3    Sl+  15:21   0:00 proc_exec.py
13980  0.0  0.0 651924  9780 pts/3    Sl+  15:21   0:00 proc_exec.py
```

The places they are hanging are.

```
 with ProcessPoolExecutor(
```

And, when creating the `mp.dict()`

```
self.data = mp.Manager().dict()
```

Can anyone please let me know the issues of this code or how to handle this? Thank you.